# Avoiding long list of elif, making if loop more efficient and dynamic

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to check the id compare it IDList if they are the same it should write the
Is there a better solution for this?
Note: chatid is grabbed realtime

```
api=[1232312,123123,1231231]
IDList=[-100123123,100123123,100123123]

try:
    if chatid==IDList[0]:
        my_event_handler.id=api[0]
        print("hook1")
    elif chatid==IDList[1]:
        my_event_handler.api=api[1]
        print("hook2")
    elif chatid==IDList[2]:
        my_event_handler.id=api[2]
        print("hook3")
    elif chatid==IDList[3]:
        my_event_handler.id=api[3]
        print("hook4")
    elif chatid==IDList[4]:
        my_event_handler.id=api[4]
        print("hook5")
```

This works well.

What I was thinking to do it a for loop `for x in range(amount):` to have the prefect numbers of hooks. But how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 for i in range(len(IDList)):
    if chatid == IDList[i]:
        my_event_handler.id=api[i]
        print("hook" + str(i+1))
        break # You got the answer, exit the loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If the indices are always regular like that, you can do something like this:

```py
for i, id_ in enumerate(IDList):
    if chatid == id_:
        my_event_handler.id=api[i]
        print(f"hook{i+1}")
        break # if you only need to find the first match, exit the loop here
```

Answer (score 0):

If `api` and `IDList` will always have the same number of elements, you can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over both lists together, and avoid using index-based lookup.

Adding [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) only so that you have a counter for printing "hook", starting at 1. If it's not needed, remove that.

```py
for idx, (api_num, ID) in enumerate(zip(api, IDList), start=1):
    if chatid == ID:
        my_event_handler.id = api_num
        print(f'hook{idx}')
        break  # exit once found, important for the `else`
else:
    # !!! `else` for the `for`, not for the `if`
    # execution reaches here if the loop was not broken, or lists are empty
    # handle as needed. raising error here as an example
    raise ValueError(f'chatid not found: {chatid}')
    # or assign it a default api and hook
```